# USB on Mac (how to use digital to analog converter on mac with cocoa)

Tags: cocoa, macos, usb

I have to play an audio file on digital to analog converter (Silverstone digital to analog converter Model number DB01S) on Mac ox x 10.6 with cocoa.

I used USBSimpleExample from apple but i am always getting this error

"dealWithInterface: unable to open interface. ret = e00002c5"

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: (Please don't post duplicates; I'm sure somebody who knows this area will be along before too long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[how to get Audio Device UID to pass into NSSound's setPlaybackDeviceIdentifier:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983984/how-to-get-audio-device-uid-to-pass-into-nssounds-setplaybackdeviceidentifier)

Answer (score 0):

You use Core Audio, not Cocoa.